# Libc's environ is zero on Android/Intel

Tags: android, android-ndk, libc

Why would the value of `libc`'s global variable `environ` be zero on Android/Intel?

I have a piece of third party native code that unconditionally dereferences `environ` as provided by `libc`. It occasionally crashes on Android Intel devices; last time observed on ASUS ME371MG tablet with Intel Atom Z2420 under Android 4.2.1. I could not reproduce it on the emulator with the same 4.2.1.

The code in question is in a shared object (SO) startup code. The startup code is being invoked, judging by the crash stack, by the first method call into said SO (as performed from yet another SO).

I've never seen this crash on Android/ARM systems.

I wonder if I can fix that by forcibly setting `environ` to something sensible from the caller code. When multiple SO's are loaded into a process, do they share the libc data?

Related to [this](http://mantis.freepascal.org/view.php?id=24519).

Comment: Looks like resetting `environ` to a somewhat sensible value before the SO-loading function call call helps. Still, this looks like a libc/android bug to me.

Comment: It's declared in bionic/libc/bionic/libc_init_common.c, initialized in `__libc_init_common`.  Looks pretty straightforward in the jellybean sources.  Could something be trampling the value to NULL?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, lacking hardware; is environ ever written to?